# Making SVG the equal width of <text> element within it

Tags: html, css, svg

In this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xtxd6r8t/ - I have an `<svg>` element which is housing some text within a `<text>` tag. When I inspect the `<svg>` and drill down the the `<text>` element I can see that its width is equal to the total length of the copy. However, the `<svg>` element is much taller and wider. Is there a way of making the `<svg>` element take it's width and height off the child `<text>` element?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="10" y="20" stroke="none" fill="red">
    SVG Colored Text
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.x + bbox.width  + "px");
svg.setAttribute("height",bbox.y + bbox.height + "px");
```

```css
svg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="image">
  <text x="10" y="20" stroke="none" fill="red">
    SVG Colored Text SVG Colored Text
  </text>
</svg>
```

i have modified your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xtxd6r8t/3/)

Comment: Modified the code to change width dynamically to set with your text

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: Welcome :) @Frazer Findlater